# Setting up a NFS Server on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, nfs, file-sharing, bsd

I need to setup an NFS Server on FreeBSD, I have gone through a couple guides to try and get it running but can't quite get it going.  I have the server running, but I seem to be having trouble setting up the /etc/exports file correctly.  I have tried the following lines and all have given me errors saying that their is a bad line in the exports file when I try and and reload it.

```
/home -alldirs -network 192.168.1.106
/home machinename1
/home/user -network 192.168.1.0 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

What am I missing and what should I check?

Answer (score 1):

Your first line looks malformed (you're exporting to a network but it looks like you're naming a host)

If that's not it start with standard troubleshooting: Remove all except one line (start with `/home machinename1`) & get that working first. Add new lines and reload/test until you find one that breaks it.

When you know which line(s) are causing the problem it's easier to troubleshoot :)

Comment: I have not had any of those lines in the same file, they have all be tried independently

Comment: hmm... now that's strange: The second line is definitely valid (as long as it can figure out what address `machine1` maps to).  What error is mountd giving you before the "bad line" message?

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error message you're getting?

Is it possible there's already an entry for /home earlier in your /etc/exports file?

Despite the error, does /home show up as being shared through `exportfs`?